# How to Automatically Send a Tweet Every Time You Post on your website or vice versa. (Without the use of Wordpress)

Tags: php, web, twitter

I would like to know if it's feasible. I've seen options for Wordpress but not a way to do it via SQL or a web dev. language.

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: Basically the end goal would be to have tweets formated as a post in a blog page without having to embed the twitter account.